# is it not good to use cacheStorage outside serviceWorker ?why?

Tags: javascript, web, browser-cache, service-worker

In the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage page, it tell us that:

> The CacheStorage interface represents the storage for Cache objects. It provides a master directory of all the named caches that a ServiceWorker, other type of worker or window scope can access (you don't have to use it with service workers, even though that is the spec that defines it) and maintains a mapping of string names to corresponding Cache objects.

so, i want to know.Is it better to use cacheStorage in ServiceWorker than in Window scope? why?

As nobody answer that, i want to share what i think.

In my opinion, there are several advantages.

First of all, serviceWorker is handled by another thread, which make it more efficient.

The next one, serviceWorker can simply add to old website without changing code, while you have to rewrite the ajax code etc, when you plan to use it in window scope.

The last but not least, you can run this when your page has been shut down.For example, you can put sth into cache when you got the push.

However, it still make me confused. Why the browser allow the window scope to get the permission.Is it a convenient way for us to just write in the main thread? Or, that will bring us some security risk, because when our page has been xss, that hacker can get access to cache?

Comment: Late to the party here, but I think one of the primary reasons for using it in service workers is code reuse.  Rather than having to write new code to check the cache in the window scope every time before you send a request to the server, you can just go ahead and send the request, then the serviceWorker intercepts the fetch event, and checks the cache for you.  Less code for you to write and maintain.  Even if you have some cache checks that are more complicated, if the service worker can handle 80% of them, that's still less work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the browser allow the window scope to get the permission?

Service Workers do not have access to DOM elements. 
So if I want to precache some urls that are found on the current page it is much easier to do from the window scope than from the service worker.